# the steps for installing compser on windows 10

Tags: composer-php

Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The Windows OneDrive folder is not supported on PHP versions below 7.2.23 and 7.3.10.
Upgrade your PHP (7.3.5) to use this location with Composer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your question?

Comment: I think he has the same problem as me: He need to install Composer to upgrade his PHP but windows said that he need to upgrade his version to get Composer. So it's typically like a snake that's bite is tail.

Comment: Thanks for posting about PHP needing to be a higher version for it to work properly with OneDrive. I was using 7.3.6 and could not get composer to work properly. I kept getting "[ErrorException] file_get_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" among other errors. Once I updated PHP, it then started working perfectly. Been searching forums for hours trying to figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked

Answer (score 0):

If you have WAMP(or XAMP or MAMP) just desinstall it and then re-install the lastest version. You should be able to have php 7.4.0 and 7.3.12 and then you could install Composer.